# Celery worker stops after being idle for a few hours

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, celery

I have a Flask app that uses WSGI. For a few tasks I'm planning to use Celery with RabbitMQ. But as the title says, I am facing an issue where the Celery tasks run for a few minutes and then after a long time of inactivity it just dies off.

**Celery config:**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
BROKER_HEARTBEAT = 10 
BROKER_HEARTBEAT_CHECKRATE = 2.0
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = None
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955293/celery-closes-unexpectedly-after-longer-inactivity) question, I added `BROKER_HEARTBEAT` and `BROKER_HEARTBEAT_CHECKRATE`.

I run the worker inside the `venv` with `celery -A acmeapp.celery worker &` to run it in the background. And while checking the status, for the first few minutes, it shows that one node is online and gives an `OK` response. But after a few hours of the app being idle, when I check the Celery status, it shows `Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.`.

I am new to Celery and I don't know what to do now.

Comment: is this on your local machine or production servers? perhaps the production server shutsdown if it is a free dev account. What about your broker? do those connections remain active or are they dead? Do you receive any other tracebacks that might diagnose your problem..

Comment: It's on production server. Not a free account. I am not sure how to check the broker connections but the celery worker itself dies after being idle. No other tracebacks except the status response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Celery worker might be trying to reconnect to the app until it reaches the retry limit. If that is the case, setting up this options in your config file will fix that problem.

```
BROKER_CONNECTION_RETRY = True
BROKER_CONNECTION_MAX_RETRIES = 0
```

The first line will make it retry whenever it fails, and the second one will disable the retry limit.

If that solution does not suit you enough, you can also try a high timeout (specified in seconds) for your app using this option:

```
BROKER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 120
```

Hope it helps!